# Typo3 Fluid extbase- How to execute external controller?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have 2 different extension. I want to execute second controller (external) inside my first controller

Two different extension 1. Course , 2. Search

```
class CourseController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {
    /**
    * courseRepository
    *
    * @var \TYPO3\Courses\Domain\Repository\CourseRepository
    * @inject
    */
    protected $courseRepository = NULL;
    /**
     * action list
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction() {
        /** I want to access Search extension Controller (f.e searchRepository->listAction() )**/       
    }
}

class SearchRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {
    /**
    * searchRepository
    *
    * @var \TYPO3\Courses\Domain\Repository\SearchRepository
    * @inject
    */
    protected $searchRepository = NULL;
    /**
     * action list
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction() {
        $searches = $this->searchRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('searches', $searches);         
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "call"? Do you want to call an action?

Comment: Please add some Code that shows what you have tried so far, so we can elaborate that and help you find the solution.

Comment: here you want to call controller of second extension or you want to access the repository method of external extension? Please put more detail with an example

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:**

Within a Controller, you usually `forward()` or `redirect()` to delegate to a different ControllerAction, e.g. delegate to `SearchController::listAction()` of 'myExtensionKey':

```
$this->forward('list', 'Search', 'myExtensionKey');
```

or

```
$this->redirect('list', 'Search', 'myExtensionKey');
```

**Long version:**

Quote from the [MVC documentation of Flow](http://flowframework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/ModelViewController.html#forward-and-redirect) which is quite similar to Extbase MVC:

> Often, controllers need to defer execution to other controllers or
>   actions. For that to happen, TYPO3 Flow supports both, internal and
>   external redirects:
>
> - in an internal redirect which is triggered by forward(), the URI does
>     not change.
> - in an external redirect, the browser receives a HTTP
>     Location header, redirecting him to the new controller. Thus, the URI
>     changes.

The APIs are:

```
public void forward(string $actionName, string $controllerName=NULL, string $extensionName=NULL, array $arguments=NULL)

protected void redirect(string $actionName, string $controllerName=NULL, string $extensionName=NULL, array $arguments=NULL, integer $pageUid=NULL, int $delay=0, int $statusCode=303)
```

The programming API details can be found in the [Extbase API](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_mvc_1_1_controller_1_1_abstract_controller.html#ac9e12bf23f76776a8b233713773d9de2)